# CSS: Vertical-align

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How to vertical-align without using display table/table-cell or position absolute ?

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>I want to be vertical aligned</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: #parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh; display: table;
  width: 100%;}   .child {
  border: 1px solid blue; display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an another option using "Flex" property.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>I want to be vertical aligned</p>
  </div>
</div>

#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[Codepen demo link](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/Yrwyrb)

Comment: I like this solution ! @satheesh-kumar Do you think having different child classes like grow-1, grow-2 is a good idea for controlling the flex-grow ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use position relative, with top of 50% and a translation of -50%.

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>I want to be vertical aligned</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How will this work for multiple childs ? Can I make the -50% be more dynamic ?

Comment: In that case you can have a container with your multiple childs, and apply the translation to it.

Answer (score 1):

Another method could be to use a floater div

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
}
.floater {
    float:left;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  clear: both;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="floater"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>I want to be vertical aligned</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using display:flex.

**CSS**

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;     /* vertical */
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal */
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>I want to be vertical aligned</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex;`:

```
#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that I think

```
position: fixed; top: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not mind browser compatibility I would go with `flex` - see @rblarsen, @Satheesh Kumars answers.

but if you need to expand browser support, here is a more complex but rather solid solution : tested IE9+ FF Chrome and other major browsers...

check out this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kLLz0nm2/

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content">Middle aligned</div>
   <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper{
   width : 100%;
   height : 100%;
   text-align: center;
}

.content{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.middle{
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

P.S - the above `translate` solution while fairly simple can sometimes cause poor rendering issues, check out :
[image: the right version looking sharper]